# While playing Half Life 2 on ubuntu 15.04 the screen goes black and goes into lock screen sometimes

Tags: steam

As the title said , when i play Half-Life 2 sometimes the screen goes black and goes into the lockscreen , so i need to put my password and go back to the game , its quite anoying, anyone have an idea why?
Im on Ubuntu 15.04.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess would be that Ubuntu thinks that you aren't using your computer and thus puts it to sleep.

You can confirm/fix this by going into **System Settings**:

[image]

then **Brightness & Lock**:

[image]

then changing this drop-down:

[image]

to *Never*:

[image]

If the random black screen + locking stops, then you know that this is what's causing it!

Comment: Thanks i will try that.but its kind of weird that it thinks im inactive but in fact i use the system, i play a game.

Comment: Oh; that's the way to ask for a little upvote on your answer.  Dully noted. I may opy/apste this in the future thanks ;-)

Comment: @solsTiCe Well, if you *do* use it, wait a few days before posting the comment. I usually only do it if there hasn't been any activity by the OP on the question for at least two day.

Comment: I wanted to upvote but i cant i dont have enough reputation. I appreciate your answer and it was pretty helpful.

Comment: @user165275 Well, you can still accept it, if my answer did indeed fix your problem! ;) I should have said this a while ago, but welcome to Ask Ubuntu!